# Can i use polygon network to process the transaction from eth network

Tags: ethereum, matic

Can I actually process some operations in Polygon via contract deployed on Ethereum network?

I tried to use plasma bridge and pos bridge but they are acting like normal bridges just for token transfering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i actually process some operations in polygon via contract deployed on etherium network?

You cannot, or it would be very complicated.

Any bridging costs would likely be much higher than processing the data in Ethereum itself.